# Can we grant Kafka ACL for suffix(postfix) based consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to create an Kafka ACL for suffix based consumer groups (_test) rather than prefix based or wildcard based access.
In other words, I want user:principal@myrealm.com to read all data/message from topic named "sampletopic" part of a cosumer group ending with "group _test"
Please advise the appropriate ACL syntax if it is possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to grant to suffix, if it suitable to your needs you might consider changing the conventions to prefix test_

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the prefix based approach doesn't suffice our requirement and hence configured the wildcard to allow all/any groups and not for a specific group! We are controlling the authorization based on the topic names though! So in a way we still have some sort of authorization control.